# AngularJS - Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-services

Estou tentando criar um Service no AngularJS porém está ocorrendo o erro: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- OrderService

Já tentei de tudo para corrigir, acessei o Stackoverflow em Inglês e testei várias soluções e sem sucesso.

Código http://pastebin.com/xBiDiSv7

Erro que aparece no console:
 `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- OrderService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20OrderService
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.min.js:65)
    at angular.min.js:4060
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.min.js:4214)
    at angular.min.js:4065
    at getService (angular.min.js:4214)
    at invoke (angular.min.js:4244)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.min.js:4261)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:4119)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:4253)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.min.js:4103)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro aponta para a falta de referência ao módulo `$scope`. Verifique se a referência está sendo corretamente injetada.

Comment: No controller e no service coloquei a referência.

Comment: @adelmo00 Em qual linha do cógido que voc6e posto no pastebin está ocorrendo o erro?

Comment: Linha 7, se eu retirar o OrderService e a chamada dentro do init(), funciona de boa.

Comment: @adelmo00 agora vejo o problema. *Services* não podem receber diretamente a injeção de `$scope`.

Comment: Tirei o $scope e deixei apenas o $http e $location e deu certo. Muito Obrigado. Vou ler melhor a documentação parar de apanhar um pouco.